# What does `entrypoint` do in solana rust?

Tags: anchor, rust, anchor-lang, entrypoint

I am confused about this line of code:

```
 entrypoint!(process_instruction);
```

this is the from the [solana_program/macro.entrypoint](https://docs.rs/solana-program/latest/solana_program/macro.entrypoint.html)

> This macro emits the common boilerplate necessary to begin program
> execution, calling a provided function to process the program
> instruction supplied by the runtime and reporting its result to the
> runtime.

I do not understand what this statement means. Why do not projects that use `anchor_lang` package have that line of code?

Answer (score 4):

This line,  `entrypoint!(process_instruction);`, tells the compiler to begin program execution as we don't have a main function here as we have in simple rust program for example:

```
fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

In anchor projects, it is handled by the following library.
`use anchor_lang::solana_program`

In solana [official docs](https://docs.solana.com/developing/on-chain-programs/developing-rust)  it says:

> Solana Rust programs may depend directly on each other in order to gain access to instruction helpers when making cross-program invocations. When doing so it's important to not pull in the dependent program's entrypoint symbols because they may conflict with the program's own. To avoid this, programs should define an no-entrypoint feature in Cargo.toml and use to exclude the entrypoint.

> Then when other programs include this program as a dependency, they should do so using the no-entrypoint feature.